# How to do JAX-RS partial update with bean validation

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

It may seem crazy but I'm having trouble with JAX-RS partial JSON requests. For example suppose we have an entity:

```
public class Data {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private Integer c;
    /* this is flat and large object with many fields */
}

@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/data")
public Response updateData(Data d) {
    /* update database */
}
```

Now I want to let user update some fields. So user sends request like this:

```
{ "a": "data of field a" }
```

This means only update field "a". When user wants to set field "a" to null he will send `{ "a": null }`. The problem is on server side I can't decide Whether client wants to set field "a" to null or there is no field "a" in the request thus I should not touch field "a"(In both cases "a" will be null). One solution is to read `Map<String, Object>` instead of `Data`. In this way I can differentiate these two cases, but I will loose bean validation framework plus I should do lots of type casting(`Object` to `String/Integer/List<Integer>`). Is there any concise way to handle such partial update requests? I'm using Jersey 2.9 with Jackson 2.3 on Jetty.

Comment: You should use ```PATCH``` instead of ```PUT``` for partial updates like discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732423), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364110) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24012950/1353722).

Comment: Not sure that would solve the problem in general but you can consider using [the Jackson views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews). You can annotated some fields of your object with the JsonView annotation and then activate it for a certain resource method which would do a partial update.

Comment: how did you solve this? I am currently using `HasMap` and doing all the validation myself...

Comment: @Jakob Same method as you. I'm did it manually.

Comment: @MajidAzimi Thank you nice to know, did you handle invalid input for example if you have a int property and the user would send inn a string? I'm currently just hard casting and the user would get a 500 error instead of a 400 and a crappy error message. How did you solve it if you did at all?

Comment: @Jakob Jackson provides convenient methods like `isInt()` or `asInt()` in `JsonNode` which helps you gracefully handle the situation. Check it out here: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html

Comment: @MajidAzimi Thank you :D